# Verilog Subtraction and addition

Tags: verilog, digital-logic, digital-design

I am attempting to program an addition and subtraction program in Verilog. Problem is Implementation and testing in Verilog of a module that performs Addition or Subtraction, then a Mux chooses between letting go through the result of one or the other, and then Decode the selected result from binary into a 7-segment Display format. Verilog Module will have 3 inputs: two 4-bit inputs named A and B, and a select input S. Your circuit should add the two numbers and should also subtract B from A (it is as simple as having A-B in your code). Depending on the value of S (i.e. whether it’s a one or a zero), you should let either the result of the addition or the result of the subtraction through.

This is the code that I have:
    module    AddOrSubtractThenSelectAndDecodeInto7SegmentsDisplay(A,B,S,Result,Overflow,Display);

```
input [3:0] A;
input [3:0] B;
input [1:0] S;

output reg [3:0] Result;
output reg Overflow;
output reg [6:0] Display;

wire [3:0] A;
wire [3:0] B;
wire [1:0] S;



always @(A,B) begin
    if (S == 0'b0)
        {Overflow, Result} = A - B;
    else if (S == 1'b1)
        {Overflow, Result} = A + B;
    end

always @(Overflow,Result) begin
    case (Result)
        4'b0000: Display = 7'b1111110;//0
        4'b0001: Display = 7'b0110000;//1
        4'b0010: Display = 7'b1101101;//2
        4'b0011: Display = 7'b1111001;//3
        4'b0100: Display = 7'b0110011;//4
        4'b0101: Display = 7'b1011011;//5
        4'b0110: Display = 7'b1011111;//6
        4'b0111: Display = 7'b1110000;//7
        4'b1000: Display = 7'b1111111;//8
        4'b1001: Display = 7'b1111011;//9
        4'b1010: Display = 7'b1110111;//A
        4'b1011: Display = 7'b0011111;//B
        4'b1100: Display = 7'b1001110;//C
        4'b1101: Display = 7'b0111101;//D
        4'b1110: Display = 7'b1001111;//E
        4'b1111: Display = 7'b1000111;//F
        default: Display = 7'bx;
    endcase

    if (Overflow == 1)begin
        Result = 4'bx;
        Display = 7'b0011101;
    end
end


endmodule
```

When I run the instructors test bench all the lines are green except for display. It says Display[6:0] xxxxxxx and followed by red lines. I have spent 2 days looking at this trying to fix it. Any help please?

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248512/verilog-addition-and-subtraction-project

Comment: Why have you taken "S" in 2 bits, when you have only 2 options. And why are you making "Result = 4'bx", for Overflow = 1 (As from hardware point of view, you can't assign "x" to any net)?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code, is that you have done assignment on the same net, through more than 1 always block.

**Do not make assignments to the same variable from more than one always block.**

So your code should be like this :

```
input [3:0] A;
input [3:0] B;
input [1:0] S;

output [3:0] Result;
output reg Overflow;
output reg [6:0] Display;

reg [3:0] Result_reg;

wire [3:0] A;
wire [3:0] B;
wire [1:0] S;

assign Result = (Overflow) ? 4'bx : Result_reg;

always @(A,B) begin
    if (S == 0'b0)
        {Overflow, Result_reg} = A - B;
    else if (S == 1'b1)
        {Overflow, Result_reg} = A + B;
    end

always @(Overflow,Result_reg) begin
    case ({Overflow, Result_reg}) inside
        [5'b1000:5'b11111] : Display = 7'b0011101; 
        5'b00000: Display = 7'b1111110;//0
        5'b00001: Display = 7'b0110000;//1
        5'b00010: Display = 7'b1101101;//2
        5'b00011: Display = 7'b1111001;//3
        5'b00100: Display = 7'b0110011;//4
        5'b00101: Display = 7'b1011011;//5
        5'b00110: Display = 7'b1011111;//6
        5'b00111: Display = 7'b1110000;//7
        5'b01000: Display = 7'b1111111;//8
        5'b01001: Display = 7'b1111011;//9
        5'b01010: Display = 7'b1110111;//A
        5'b01011: Display = 7'b0011111;//B
        5'b01100: Display = 7'b1001110;//C
        5'b01101: Display = 7'b0111101;//D
        5'b01110: Display = 7'b1001111;//E
        5'b01111: Display = 7'b1000111;//F
        default: Display = 7'bx;
    endcase
end
```

For Verilog Coding Guidelines, you can check [Verilog Coding Guidelines](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA_rev1_2.pdf)

Moreover, I have assigned "x" in the code, as per your original code. But **I am strongly not recommending usage of "x" assignment for RTL code.**

Answer (score 0):

One line looks strange:

```
if (S == 0'b0)
```

Basically that means "number zero with zero bits". In verilog I think the format is *bits*´b*value*. Replace the **b** with **h** for hex format (and use google for rest of the options ;))

Also like said by other posters, **S** seems to be 2bit vector though only the MSB is used.

And also the **x** value does not exist in real world - it's just a way for the simulator to say "I dunno". So that will not synthesize.

Otherwise I fail to see where the same signal is assigned more than twice in different always blocks? When done in the same block it should be ok. The latter value just overrides the previous one. Google for *blocking* and *non-blocking* for more info.

**edit**: also what do you use as the stimulus? If A and B are static, they will not cause an event which in turn causes none of the *always* blocks to fire. Hence the output stays in 7'bx. Not really sure about this, but worth to check.