# Signal Result Implantation Connected To Multiple Drivers

Tags: verilog

I've been trying to implement a simple verilog program, but I consistently keep running into two error's and I can seem to find the solution. The two errors I'm receiving are:

```
1. Line 21: Empty module <AddOrSubtractThenSelectAndDecodedInto7SegmentsDisplay> remains a black box. 

2. Line 40: Signal Result[3] in unit AddOrSubtractThenSelectAndDecodedInto7SegmentsDisplay is connected to following multiple drivers:

Driver 0: output signal Result[3] of instance Latch (Result[3]).
Driver 1: output signal Result[3] of instance Latch (_i000011).
Driver 0: output signal Result[2] of instance Latch (Result[2]).
Driver 1: output signal Result[2] of instance Latch (_i000012).
Driver 0: output signal Result[1] of instance Latch (Result[1]).
Driver 1: output signal Result[1] of instance Latch (_i000013).
Driver 0: output signal Result[0] of instance Latch (Result[0]).
Driver 1: output signal Result[0] of instance Latch (_i000014).
Module AddOrSubtractThenSelectAndDecodedInto7SegmentsDisplay remains a blackbox, due to errors in its contents
```

I've attempted to find the solution prior to asking, but can't find the proper solution for my question. So my question is: Why is this happening and what is the best solution to solve this?

Here's my verilog code (without test bench):

```
module AddOrSubtractThenSelectAndDecodedInto7SegmentsDisplay(A,B,S,Result,OF,Display);

// Inputs A,B,S
input [3:0] A;
input [3:0] B;
input [1:0] S;

// Outputs OF,Result,Display
output reg [6:0] Display;
output reg [3:0] Result;
output reg OF;

reg [3:0] Result_reg;

// Wires
wire [3:0] A;
wire [3:0] B;
wire [1:0] S;

always @(A,B,S) begin
    if (S == 1)
        {OF,Result} = A + B;
    else if (S == 0)
        {OF,Result} = A - B;
end 

always @(OF,Result) begin
    case (Result) 
        5'b00000: Display = 7'b1111110;//0
        5'b00001: Display = 7'b0110000;//1
        5'b00010: Display = 7'b1101101;//2
        5'b00011: Display = 7'b1111001;//3
        5'b00100: Display = 7'b0110011;//4
        5'b00101: Display = 7'b1011011;//5
        5'b00110: Display = 7'b1011111;//6
        5'b00111: Display = 7'b1110000;//7
        5'b01000: Display = 7'b1111111;//8
        5'b01001: Display = 7'b1111011;//9
        5'b01010: Display = 7'b1110111;//A
        5'b01011: Display = 7'b0011111;//B
        5'b01100: Display = 7'b1001110;//C
        5'b01101: Display = 7'b0111101;//D
        5'b01110: Display = 7'b1001111;//E
        5'b01111: Display = 7'b1000111;//F
        default: Display = 7'bx;
    endcase

     if (OF == 1)begin
        Result = 4'bx;
        Display = 7'b0011101;
    end

end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inferring a latch here:

```
always @(A,B,S) begin
    if (S == 1)
        {OF,Result} = A + B;
    else if (S == 0)
        {OF,Result} = A - B;
    // <-- inferred latch because S=2 and S=3 is not described
end
```

Generally (level sencitive) latches are not recommend. They have value, but you need to be carful with them or you get timing and metastability issues. For more see

- [What is inferred latch and how it is created when it is missing else statement in if condition.can anybody explain briefly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22459413/1959732)
- [Why does an If statement cause a latch in verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33685205/1959732)

The second driver is because you are driving `Result` in two always blocks. It works in simulator, but is illegal for synthesis.

```
always @(OF,Result) begin
  // ...

  if (OF == 1)begin
    Result = 4'bx; // <-- second driver on 'Result'. Illegal for synthesis
    Display = 7'b0011101;
  end
end
```

Note: It is usually considered bad practice to assign something you plan to synthesize to a value to X.

To resolve the multiple driver error, you have to have all the assigments to `Result` in the same always block. Either move the assignment or merge the always blocks.

Note: Unless are required to follow strict 1995 coding practices, you should not declare the signals in the sensitivity list. Instead use auto-sensitivity list (`@*` or `@(*)`) added to verilog in 2001. You have 2001 support because 1995 does not support commas as a signal separator for sensitivity list; 1995 uses `or` as the signal separator for sensitivity list.

Answer (score 0):

I have already written an answer for the same question. You can check in the link : 
[Verilog Subtraction and addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249907/verilog-subtraction-and-addition/35251620#35251620)

You have inferred Latch, because you have taken "S" of 2 bits wide and you have not specified the value of "Result" for 2 options of the "S".

> Incomplete if or case statement can potentially be
>   synthesized into a latch. Because for tool, you didn't specify, what
>   to drive on a net for rest of the if/case condition. In this case,
>   tool will try to make a hardware, which will drive the previous values
>   for those conditions. And to do so, a Latch will be inferred.

```
always @(A,B,S) begin
    if (S == 1)
        {OF,Result} = A + B;
    else if (S == 0)
        {OF,Result} = A - B;
    // What for S == 2 or S == 3?
    // So tool thinks, that you want to have previous value of Result
    // in both cases, and hence it needs to infer a latch for Result to
    // have the previous value.
end
```

Now, you are getting multiple driver error, because "Result" is being driven through multiple always blocks.

> A "reg" variable, can't have multiple drivers. But a "wire" can
>   certainly have. So, if a net has multiple drivers, then it has to be
>   of "wire" type.